# 6 images per row no matter the screen size with image size adjusting - html css3

Tags: html, css, media-queries

im trying to achieve two rows of images (ie. 6 images in first row and 6 images in second row). When my screen  size is between 320px and 480px it gives my requirement. However, i'm not able to adjust for the other screens.

Please take a look at this link here: [sample html page](http://davidtompsalmist.com/html5/zigsaw.html)

I have found a similar question here --> [stackoverflow qs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22425006/same-number-of-fluid-tiles-in-a-row-no-matter-the-screen-width-css-jquery)

However, this is a different implementation. Ideally, i would like the two rows of images to stay as it is but the size of the image should become larger when my screen size increases.

Any tips/ideas or resources to implement this kind of solution would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want them to be 6 per row always, why not just have `ul>li>ul>li*6` ?

Comment: Let me try and reply again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure of your question, and if you code provide a little code that would help. Anyhow I would go about doing something like this:

CSS

```
#image {
    min-width: 320px; /*Sets a width of 320px*/
    width: 16.66%; /*If page gets bigger the image will become 1/6 of page's width*/
}
```

So basically, set the `min-width`, and then after that set it to what percentage of the page you would like it to be. The `width` will **ONLY** be used when `min-width` is true.

**EDIT**

I just realized how my answer was kind of completely wrong (Tiredness was a factor). Take in to account the following example:

*HTML*

```
<div id="holder">
    <image class="image" src="">
    <image class="image" src="">
    <image class="image" src="">
    <image class="image" src="">
    <image class="image" src="">
    <image class="image" src="">
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
#holder {
    min-width: 320px;
    width: 100%;
}

.image {
    width: 16.66%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Simply, what this will do is make the 6 images together have a minimum width of `320px`. Now if the screen size gets SMALLER than `320px`, the `#holder`, the item that is holding the images, will then go off the page. Yet, if the page gets BIGGER than `320px` then the images will each take `16.66%` (1/6) of the `#holder`'s width, which is 1/6 of the page width. So With those two combined values you can make it so the images will expand, but never get smaller than.

Comment: You meant the min-width will apply to webpage?  and width percentage values gets applied when my web page screen size moves above 320px? This is new to me. Let me try

Comment: Hello, sorry I went to bed. Now that I am reading this correctly, let me re-write my answer.

Comment: Its making more sense to me now. Can you check this link --> http://responsivetest.net/#u=davidtompsalmist.com/fixedresponsive.html|1280|800|1.5  im not sure why the border is not covering the inner images.

Comment: I don't see where the code is, but I am pretty sure I know what the issue is. Your images are overflowing, but your div is not expanding. Why you may be wondering? You div most likely has a height of `??px`, but it should be auto.

Comment: I have updated the file now. Direct link here: davidtompsalmist.com/fixedresponsive.html  The image overflow issue is fixed. Its  commented under .container class in the css.  Now, im faced with another  problem, i want the .container to have size of only 400px so that the whole page is not occupied by this .container containing images when we load the webpage from desktop computer.

Comment: Ok, there are a couple of things you can do. First off you can make anything that is out of the `400px` invisible. To do that you could do `overflow: hidden`. Now the more reasonable, and thing you should do it make it so it scrolls. To do this simply add these two lines of CSS: `height: 400px` and `overflow-y: scroll`. That is assuming of course that you want it to overflow down (and not sideways). Anything else I can help with? :) By the way, if I have helped you, maybe vote up my response (or mark it as the correct answer)? :D

Comment: Let me try and get back again. Actually, the issue was when i give .container{ width: 400px; } the whole .container block is floated to the left of webpage. Also, when i reduce browser screen size it stops being responsive. Ideally, im looking  for the layout to be responsive and the max width should be 400px.  Link  again: Just so you know, can you check this link please. http://davidtompsalmist.com/fixedresponsive.html ,

Comment: OK, I will take a look at it! :)

Comment: @cssnewbie, I am a bit confused on what you would like done. The link you provided takes me to a bunch of squares :( Please explain what you would like done, and a bit more code if possible please! :)

Comment: Please have a look at this image. davidtompsalmist.com/game.png , this is what i want and  if you load this webpage: davidtompsalmist.com/fixedresponsive.html  you will see that its almost becoming like the picture above. Im trying to arrange 25 block of images to be responsive inside .container element.

Comment: @cssnewbie, I am sorry, I guess I just don't understand what you are asking me :( The page you linked seems to be entirely responsive. Do you want the pictures to have a `min-width`? Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
#sortable li {
  float: left;
  background: #fff;
  vertical-align: top;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ddd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
#sortable li:nth-child(6n+1) {
  clear: left;
}
```

Comment: Something new li nth child . Let me try this.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it will help

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper > div {
    background: #737373;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 16.66666666666667%;
    padding-bottom: 16.66666666666667%;          
}
.wrapper > div img {
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div>
    <img src="http://g02.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1LApRIXXXXXcAXXXXq6xXFXXXC/Car-Stereo-GPS-Navigation-for-Mazda-6-2002-2008-Auto-Radio-DVD-Player-Multimedia-Head-Unit.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="https://static.artfire.com/uploads/product/2/592/71592/8271592/8271592/large/380_auto_nickel_bullet_push_pins_-_set_of_4_807a34be.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://www.steptwo.cz/media/catalog/product/d/e/detska-postel-auto-corvette-821500-c.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTi6yvNhbL_qWDmf0CqCjObIKLOEV8KobtxeYsNPnk0tynHaer0xw" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ_WGLGUhf-E74PgPVnISsV2RkX4ahN-jhF7UpOghGmyrI8iTn_bw" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://g02.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1LApRIXXXXXcAXXXXq6xXFXXXC/Car-Stereo-GPS-Navigation-for-Mazda-6-2002-2008-Auto-Radio-DVD-Player-Multimedia-Head-Unit.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
    
<div>
    <img src="http://g02.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1LApRIXXXXXcAXXXXq6xXFXXXC/Car-Stereo-GPS-Navigation-for-Mazda-6-2002-2008-Auto-Radio-DVD-Player-Multimedia-Head-Unit.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="https://static.artfire.com/uploads/product/2/592/71592/8271592/8271592/large/380_auto_nickel_bullet_push_pins_-_set_of_4_807a34be.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://www.steptwo.cz/media/catalog/product/d/e/detska-postel-auto-corvette-821500-c.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTi6yvNhbL_qWDmf0CqCjObIKLOEV8KobtxeYsNPnk0tynHaer0xw" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ_WGLGUhf-E74PgPVnISsV2RkX4ahN-jhF7UpOghGmyrI8iTn_bw" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://g02.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1LApRIXXXXXcAXXXXq6xXFXXXC/Car-Stereo-GPS-Navigation-for-Mazda-6-2002-2008-Auto-Radio-DVD-Player-Multimedia-Head-Unit.jpg" alt="" />
</div>    
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/5t1ew71r/)

Comment: I'm testing your example. Much appreciated for your effort and time. I'll reply again once i finish testing.

Comment: If i give a height of 500px to the wrapper class and background of blue it looks good. When i resize, how do we resize the wrapper to follow the image ?

Comment: When i give width value to Wrapper, the image resize won't happen.. What if i want to wrap the two rows of images inside my wrapper by giving some width to my wrapper because i don't want the two rows of image to occupy till the corner of my webpage.

Answer (score 0):

With angular-material's flex helper properties ([fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/w0Lzb9c1/1/)):

```
<style>
  .image-container{
    height: 200px;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .image-container{
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/#abc/300x600)
  }
</style>
<div layout="row" id="slides-container">
  <div flex="33" class="one-third" layout="row">
    <div flex="50" class="one-sixth image-container"> </div>
    <div flex="50" class="one-sixth image-container"> </div>
  </div>
  <div flex="33" class="one-third" layout="row">
    <div flex="50" class="one-sixth image-container"> </div>
    <div flex="50" class="one-sixth image-container"> </div>
  </div>
  <div flex="33" class="one-third" layout="row">
    <div flex="50" class="one-sixth image-container"> </div>
    <div flex="50" class="one-sixth image-container"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```